# Voice call record on Nexus4

Tags: call, record, voice

I tried recording voice call on Nexus 4. I used amix, aplay & also tried using "Incall REC" use case. Though arec generates the file, but it has no voice. Can someone please tell me if this is supported at HW level. I found some blogs claiming it is supported on APQ8064. So I am confused.